# Custom Select Boxes for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for suggestions on where to find good looking custom select boxes that even look and work fantastic in IE8.

Most of the custom scripts I've seen so far work well, but when it comes to IE8, they usually take a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one that works well:

jQuery UI selectmenu version 1.1.0

https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu
http://docs.jquery.com/UI

Answer (score 1):

[Have you tried Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)? I've used it and it seemed to work well. YMMV.

They say "Legacy support for IE8 is also enabled." I'm not sure what that means, though. I'm guess things like gradients aren't in there.

Answer (score 0):

One word - [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/)